# ExpressJS: How to send data to URL

Tags: node.js, express

I have a post request which redirects to a new route as you can see

```
 //POST login 
 app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
    userLogin(req.body, function(response){
        if(response == true){
            //Activate player login in db
            loginPlayerDB(req.body.username);
            getPlayerId(req.body.username, function(id){
                res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/:id/profile');
            });
        } else{
            res.send(500, "Username or Password is incorrect");
        }
    })
});
```

This function gets called

```
 function getPlayerId(username, callback){
    let sql = "SELECT PlayerId FROM users WHERE Username = (?)";
    var values = [username];
    db.query(sql, values, function(err, result, fields){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
               return callback(result);
        }
    })
}
```

It redirects to this route

```
app.get('/:id/profile', function(req,res){
    res.render('profile/profile');
})
```

Everything works great except the URL on the new page is

```
http://localhost:3000/:id/profile
```

When it should be something like

```
http://localhost:3000/6/profile
```

If the player has an id of 6. How do I fix this

//Solution.

Thank you to MadWard for the help. My mistake was that in my getPlayerId function, I return result, which is an array, instead of result[0].PlayerId in order to get the specific id I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are literally redirecting to `/:id/profile`. This is a string, it is fixed, and will always be '/:id/profile'.

What you want to do instead is, using **template strings**:

```
        getPlayerId(req.body.username, function(id){
            res.redirect(`${req.baseUrl}/${id}/profile`);
        });
```

Using normal string concatenating like you were doing:

```
        getPlayerId(req.body.username, function(id){
            res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/' + id + '/profile');
        });
```

Comment: When I use your string concatenation, I get http://localhost:3000/undefined/profile

Comment: Then the `id` returned by your `getPlayerId` function isn't an `id` string, but an object. Go check it out!

Comment: You are correct. When I console.log the function it prints [ RowDataPacket { PlayerId: 1 } ]

Comment: You will have to modify getPlayerId to return `obj[0].PlayerId` instead of `obj` in the callback. I can't give exact name of obj since the code for getPlayerId isn't available in the main post. If you want more accurate help, you'll need to post the code for `getPlayerId` in the main post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188636/discussion-between-madward-and-workkkkk).